# How can i compare data from database with for exp integer in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I try like this gives me error

```
@if ( {{ Auth::user()->gender }} == '1') {

<p> Something </p>

}

@endif
```

say: syntax error, unexpected '<'

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Questions here are expected to be __specific programming problems__ expressed _clearly_. Please take a __[tour]__.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax that you're looking for is:

```
@if (Auth::user()->gender == '1')
    <!-- Content here is HTML, not PHP -->
@endif
```

The curly braces (`{` and `}`) are not required within the parantheses, Blade will interpret that as PHP.  There is no need for curly braces surrounding the contents of the if-statement.  This is analogous to `if ($condition): endif;` in normal PHP.

Please take a moment and read the documentation on [Blade templating](http://laravel.com/docs/templates#blade-templating).